# How to send an action from google maps click event listener?

Tags: ember.js

I have multiple pins rendering in google maps. When user clicks in any of the pins I want to be able to trigger the _activeRoute action. For some reason when I do the below nothing happens.

```
action:{
   _activeRoute:fuction(){
   console.log('hello world');
},

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(mapService) {
    this.sendAction('_activeRoute');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside `function` callback isn't pointing to component or other Ember object instance. You have to use another variable to call method `sendAction` of correct object:

```
let that = this;

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(mapService) {
    that.sendAction('_activeRoute');
});
```

Comment: when doing that way, what I get is this error(Uncaught TypeError: that.sendAction is not a function)